# Why am I getting a null reference exception? Tagged correctly.

Tags: c#, syntax-error, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to do some simple 2D raycasting and I am completely lost. I am getting a null reference exception at line 25 of the following script. I made sure the enemy is tagged as enemy, and yet when I try to get the tag I get the error. I realize now that the error only occurs when I click on the sky, not on an untagged game object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera cam;

    public GameObject enemy;

    public Transform fireStart;

    GameObject target;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        float inputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
        float inputY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
        fireStart = transform.FindChild("GunEnd");
    }
    void ShootGun()
    {
        Debug.Log("Fire");
        Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, 
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
        Vector2 firePointPos = new Vector2(fireStart.position.x, fireStart.position.y);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firePointPos, mousePos - firePointPos, 100f);
        if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit");
        }
        else if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Untagged"))
        {
            Debug.Log("No hit");
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            ShootGun();
        }
    }

}
```

Help GREATLY appreciated

Comment: Just to be sure, the line that throw the exception is: RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firePointPos, mousePos - firePointPos, 100f);

Comment: @Backs And I would say this is not duplicated question in the sense he is asking for help for his particular case. No what is a NullReferenceException. Maybe he will be able to see where the issue is by reading the question you link but maybe we can help him if you unblock it

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre This is very much a 'debug this for me' question. The linked question provides an explanation as to *why* this happens, and *how* to fix it. There's nothing unique in this question.

Comment: @Backs totally agree with the 'debug this for me' but the problem the guy is facing is not because of a wrong understanding of C# or NullReferenceException, that is just the result of using wrong the Unity API when he tries to refer a component of a GameObject (which of course generates the exception). If it is ok for you an Rob I could edit the question to focus in the Unity API problem instead of in the general C# exception as he did

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre Sure, if you're able to edit it into a version which isn't just 'why am I getting a null reference exception?' I'll happily re-open. Make sure to ping me